# Object detection using EfficientDet

Tags: python, object-detection

Unfortunately I don't have a specific question because I just started looking into this hours ago but I am trying to write a script that will use EfficientDet to detect object in some images acquired using cv2. Any pointers or help on how to achieve this is much appreciated.

Currently I am going over the information presented here:

- https://www.kaggle.com/code/yassinealouini/efficientdet-meets-pytorch-lightning/notebook
- https://github.com/rwightman/efficientdet-pytorch

I understand how to use cv2 and retrieve the images, I don't know how to get my hands on this effdet model and use it in a script that is part of a larger application in order to get detections from it.